# Loading a large javascript array from JSON(db query results) without crashing the page?

Tags: javascript, arrays, browser, crash, large-data

I'm trying to load a million rows from a database query in chunks and keep it on the same page but paginated. Currently I have a button that retrieves 50,000 chunks using a LIMIT between and then append it to the end of the table. The query results is written to a JSON file which is retrieved onto a paginated table on the page.

However the browser crashes shortly after loading it. Currently, there is a load more results button that appends a new query onto the existing JSON file which is then loaded into an array of rows in a paginated table. However upon reaching about 160MB JSON file size, roughly 250 thousand rows, the browser would crash.

Currently, my table is already paginated, retrieved from an array and filtered using angularJS filter on ng-repeat of the huge array to display only 1000 results per page on the table, and the load more query will append the new results to the end of the table. The reason for appending is because a single large query takes too long and I would like to have access to previous results loaded (for csv export reasons), is there a way to have a million rows paginated and not crash the page?

Thanks in advance, hope you can help.

Comment: I'd advice you to break it into smaller chunks, and only do the db query on a new page request, ie. use `LIMIT X, X`... this way you'd only need to run a count first to see how many rows / pages there wil be...

Comment: Trying to load this large dump of information into memory is what's causing your browser to crash. You might want to load each page and save it to local storage instead. This would free up a lot of memory, and hopefully won't crash your app. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Like webeno said, what you should probably do is if you're going to use it via a web interface, using pagination or even a pagination that as you scroll down, you'll load more content. If you do it that way, then you have to remember what entries should be deleted once you get passed a certain point and re-added later. This is because your browser will load a considerable amount of data without it. Paginate and if needed implement a search feature. If you need all that data somewhere else, consider exporting it as a file. But your question is ambiguous to really answer :X

Comment: Thank you all for your help so far, to clarify. I am retrieving my data in portions of 50,000 that appends to the last page of a paginated table on the page which is essentially filtering a js array to display only X rows at a given time. From what it seems, I've been getting suggestions of only displaying that specific instance between a row range from a new page request on the page at a given time. However, doing so will prevent me from exporting the previous page results as it essentially wipes it unless I go to that page. What if I want to export everything from the start until here

Answer (score 0):

Use smaller pieces of code and use local storage to save your code. In addition, run a count the number of pages that will be in the code to know how to break it up.

Comment: How would I deal with a growing number of pages when appending more to the table from loading more, would I create new local storage variables for each new paginated page? Suppose I have 20pages and each time I load more I append 20 more pages to the paginated table. Would I create another 20 new local storage variables for it? So each time I select a page, I will be loading HTML markup from a local storage variable and each time I load more pages it will create more localstorage variables?